# How can I create and update two different models in the same page in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, `Group and Type`.

```
Group:
------
group_code, group_name

Type:
-----
group_code, type_code, type_name, use_in_location, type_summary
```

`group_code` is the `foreign_key` to `types`.

Each `Group` has `multiple Types`. I want to create a form for `Group` and `Type` in a same page. So When I click edit of the `Group` table, it will also show the `Type` fields to edit in the same page.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to create separate `controllers`, `views` for both `group` and `types`? Please somebody suggest with an examples.

Thanks

Comment: It can be achieved using nested forms.

Comment: Because you didn't show what you done to achieve this. You just ask someone to do what you want without tying yourself.

Comment: I asked suggestions.. idea.. Didn't asked to finish this task.

Comment: You have suggestions. Try to implement them and show what happend. And then we will help you to do the reset. This is a long explanation [why](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should check railscasts.com episode on nested forms. [Episode 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [Episode 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)